# msinfo32 /nfo emits XML with translated tags

Tags: windows, xml, localization

I'm working on some system data collection tools for an application I'm involved in supporting, and have run into an exciting wrinkle.

I wanted to capture an `msinfo32 /nfo` report as part of the collected data, since it's so comprehensive. But there's a fun problem.

The XML from a system with German as set as the display language looks like this:

```
<Data>
<Element><![CDATA[Betriebsystemname]]></Element>
<Wert><![CDATA[Microsoft Windows 10 Pro]]></Wert>
</Data>
```

"wert" is the german word for "Value".

So some, but not all, tags appear to get translated to the local language. Just for fun.

(It's also absolutely ghastly who-designed-this-crock XML, but that I can work around).

I'm looking for a way to override the tag translation, or failing that a way to run one program in Windows with a different display language. On a UNIX system I'd just set `LC_ALL=C` or `LC_ALL=en_US`. On Windows, not so much. I'm aware of `AppLocale`, but it seems to be for legacy non-Unicode programs and mainly focused on dealing with charsets.